# Auto add number between 1 to 4 in columns using devexpress gridview?

Tags: loops, gridview, devexpress

I am making a c# Winform application using a DevExpress GridView that imports an Excel sheet. On it has 11 columns and many rows. I want to be able to sort it and group it by some column which is why I need to add auto numbers (1,2,3&4) in the column called (Break) using a button. I searched a lot and trying to do a loop, but I fail can any one help me?

```
   DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col = gridView2.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("Break");
          for( int i = 0; (i < 5)
          {

          i++;


            col = i.ToString(); 

           }
```

Comment: You need to include some code, so that anyone trying to help you know what you have already done and where something is missing / seems wrong.

Comment: DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col = gridView2.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("Break");

          for( int i = 0; (i < 5)
          {

          i++;
           

            col = i.ToString(); 
           
           }

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to set the cell value to the i.ToString() but instead you are assigning it to actual Break column rather than setting it to the value of a cell. You need to loop through the rows within the grid. This hasn't been tested but something along these lines should work:

```
Int32 count = 0;
public object GetNextNum()
{
    if (count >= 5)
        count = 0;
    count++;
    return count;
}

DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col = gridView2.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("Break");

for (int rowHandle = 0; rowHandle < gridView.RowCount; rowHandle++)
{
    grdView2.SetRowCellValue(rowHandle, col, GetNextNum())
}
```

Note that this will only handle positive rowHandles so it will not set the cell value for any group headers as they have negative row handles (i.e. The top group's row handle is -1. The following group handle is -2, and so on).

Check out this article which has an example of traversing a grid with and without grouped columns as it may be useful: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A1245

```
private static void TraverseRows(GridView gridView)
{
    if (gridView.GroupCount == 0)
        for (int rowHandle = 0; rowHandle < gridView.RowCount; rowHandle++)
        {
            foreach (GridColumn gc in gridView.Columns)
                WriteString(String.Format("{0} ", gridView.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowHandle, gc)));
            WriteString("\r\n");
        }
    else
    {
        // Get the list of grouped columns
        List<GridColumn> groupedColumnsList = new List<GridColumn>();
        foreach (GridColumn groupedColumn in gridView.GroupedColumns)
            groupedColumnsList.Add(groupedColumn);

        for (int rowHandle = -1; gridView.IsValidRowHandle(rowHandle); rowHandle--)
        {
            WriteString(gridView.GetGroupRowDisplayText(rowHandle) + "\r\n");

            if (gridView.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, 0) > -1)

                for (int childRowHandle = 0; childRowHandle < gridView.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle); childRowHandle++)
                {
                    WriteString("-- ");
                    foreach (GridColumn gc in gridView.Columns)
                    {
                        if (groupedColumnsList.Contains(gc)) continue;
                        WriteString(String.Format("{0} ", gridView.GetRowCellDisplayText(gridView.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, childRowHandle), gc)));
                    }
                    WriteString("\r\n");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This artical also explains setting cell row values in DevEpxress grid views using ColumnView.SetFocusedValue, ColumnView.SetFocusedRowCellValue, ColumnView.SetRowCellValue and ColumnView.EditingValue: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument753

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated my answer to provide some more info.